# Replacing '"' with '/"'? Why doesn't code = code.replace('"', '\"') work?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace all of the quotation marks in a string with escaped quotation marks, but the replace function didn't seem to work, as `bool` returned true when I looped though the replaced string to find a quotation mark. Why is this?

```
        code = code.replace('"', '\"')

        bool = false
        i = 0
        while (i < code.length)
          if (code[i] == '"')
             bool = true
          i++

        alert(bool)
```

Comment: Try `code = code.replace('"', '\\"')`

Comment: Try code.replace(/"/g,'/\"')

Comment: why it should return false?

Comment: Because ..`'\"' === '"'`

Comment: @user2864740 i dont get it, please provide more info http://jsfiddle.net/Dk85C/

Comment: @Sharky `\"` is an *escape* which translates to `"` - see [String literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#String_literals)

Comment: @user2864740 so again, why it should ALERT false?

Comment: @Sharky The above code won't alert false (the fiddle linked did not alert false either), assuming that the `code` string contains at least one double-quote.

Comment: @user2864740 thats exactly why i am wondering why this piece of code should return false? (as OP implies that alerting TRUE is wrong)

Comment: @user2864740 "function didn't seem to work, as bool returned true"

Comment: @Sharky The OP *expects* false, which would mean that there are no double-quotes in `code` after the replacement. However it is true because there *are* double-quotes per `'\"' === '"'` (and the replace changes the first double-quote .. with a double quote). Not being a global replace is another issue, of course.

Comment: @user2864740 can you please provide a fiddle that does the replaceing with escaped `"` and `if (code[i] == '"') bool = true` and alerts FALSE?

Comment: @Sharky The whole loop/alert is irrelevant except to show that there *are* double-quotes remaining, run this: `'foo"bar'.replace('"', '\"')` - the result is the string containing `foo"bar`, just as the result of `"fooXbar".replace("X", "X")` is `fooXbar`. It can be shown that there *was* a (useless and undetectable) replacement, consider:  `"fooXbarX".replace("X", "-")` which results in `foo-barX`.

Comment: @user2864740 seems no one pays attention to what i asked, or i didnt explained good enough

Comment: @Sharky Again, the loop/alert is irrelevant, except to show a case (which is that there is at least one double-quote remaining after the replacement) - the result from running the expressions above is much easier to understand. (The last expression also shows that replace is *not* "global" by default.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52486/discussion-between-sharky-and-user2864740)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for is

```
code.replace(/"/g,'\\"')
```

Omit the *g* if you only want to replace the first occurrence, not all of them.

Comment: Can you explain to me how this code works please? :)

Comment: @Regnarg: What are you wondering about? The `/"/g` or the `'\\"'`?

Comment: @FelixKling: More of the first one, but it would be nice if you could explain both of them :)

Comment: @Regnarg: There is nothing much to say about `/"/g`. It's an regex literal (`/.../`) which matches `"`. The `g`lobal modifier at the end tells `replace` to find all occurrences of the pattern. See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for more information about regular expressions. Regarding `'\\"'`, the ``\`` is the escape character in strings. If you want to produce a literal ``\`` in a string, you have to escape it, thus it becomes ``\\``.